# Which load resistance is connected to generator U2?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, resistance, differential, load

I have this op amp and one of the questions says

> Which load resistance is connected to generator U2?

[image]

---

This is my attempt but I can not confirm if it right.
No it's not homework, it examples I'm trying to solve that might help me for my exam.
There are unfortunately any answers so I don't know if it's right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations looks alrigt regarding to the load that is connected to U2. It will be infinite at dc (as long as the OP is ideal) and R1 at high frequencies.

But as this is an exam question, they can sometimes be a bit “gotcha” and the correct answer might be as simple as “R1”, much dependent on the course and the examinator. Therefore there is a good idea to accompany the answer with some text to answer different interpretations of the question if no clarification of the examiners intent can be confirmed. That way it can be made clear that you understand the subject but might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you. This is what's bothering me. I don't know for sure if that answer is right.